# Formik ErrorMessage - Typescript Error "cannot be used as a JSX component"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, formik

I'm getting the following Typescript error while using [Formik's](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage)  component in Next13:

```
'ErrorMessage' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<ErrorMessageProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)
```

I had no problems with this on a previous pure React stack, I guess I need to update some typings but not sure which, any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Can you also provide the code snippet where you're using the component ?

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest starting with updating React and its types

```
yarn upgrade react@latest react-dom@latest @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```

next you'll possibly have to update any other packages that you have installed that depend on a certain react version